# How can I append Geometry Node objects from the asset browser without spilling submeshes everywhere?

Tags: geometry-nodes, asset-browser

When appending geometry nodes objects into a different file using the Asset Browser, it places the original objects in addition to the geonode object, if the node network point instances another model. I've demonstrated this below (the gears could be any mesh object, like a monkey head).

Here's the original nodegraph setup.
[image]

And the result of appending it into a new file. Notice the superfluous gear mesh to the right.
[image]

Is there a way to avoid this behavior from the asset browser, and have it only place the geometry node object, similar to how instanced collections are appended?

Comment: I think the only solution is to plug a new input from the group input node and set the field in the modifier panel of each object. Also I'd make sure the object isnt set as default in the group input options. Didn't test it though

Comment: If you are only interested in the geometry node group, you can use the *Node Presets* addon. Instead of using the asset browser, you simply use a blend file that contains all your node groups. However, this doesn't quite work at the moment, so see the following entry: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/260854/145249

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer" so that this question will not continue to be displayed as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 1):

In the *Asset Browser* often used objects can be saved together with their attached modifiers. This is good if you want to reuse various meshes.

However, if it is only about *Geometry Nodes*, which are finally a modifier of an object, then the *Asset Browser* is not suitable, because with an asset **there is always a geometry/object involved**.

Exactly for this there is the Blender integrated addon [Node Presets](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/node/node_presets.html).

This addon, which has been working stably since version 3.2, allows you to access your node groups without having to use geometry.

If you use a lower version, you would have to take a detour using this alternative: [Node Presets Extended](https://github.com/quellenform/blender-NodePresetsExtended)

> Here you can read more about the topic:
>
> [How can I use custom node groups as node templates/presets?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/260854/145249)